# Need to find Closed form solution to interesting problem

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, inequality, proof-verification, closed-form

$A= (1+x)(1+x-y)^{1/y}$

$B= x(1+x)^{1/y}$

for $y\in(0,1)$ and $x > 0$;

I want to show that A > B, but could not prove it mathematically. I run a simulation and it shows that in fact A > B, but I need closed form solution. Will be glad if you help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint:* Apply [Bernoulli's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli%27s_inequality) to
$$
 \frac AB = \frac{1+x}{x} \left( 1- \frac{y}{1+x}\right)^{1/y}
$$

Comment: thank you for comment. But if we apply Bernoulli's inequality to $(1- \frac{y}{1+x})^{1/y}$ part it states that it is greater or equal to $1 - \frac{1}{1+x}$. So despite first part $\frac{1+x}{x}$ is greater than 1 the second part might be less than 1 and it will not prove that A/B is greater or equal to 1. If I made mistake, could you please clarify your solution. Thanks.

Comment: @Aboka: You get $\frac AB > \frac{1+x}{x} (1 - \frac{1}{1+x})$. Now simplify the expression on the right-hand side ...

Comment: I got you. Thanks a lot)